# Android facebook-login library 11.2.0 crashes Android 12 - Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login

I'm using Firebase with facebook-login and receiving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: my.app.id: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at com.facebook.AccessTokenManager.setTokenExpirationBroadcastAlarm(AccessTokenManager.kt:121)
    at com.facebook.AccessTokenManager.setCurrentAccessToken(AccessTokenManager.kt:94)
    at com.facebook.AccessTokenManager.setCurrentAccessToken(AccessTokenManager.kt:47)
    at com.facebook.AccessToken$Companion.setCurrentAccessToken(AccessToken.kt:428)
    at com.facebook.AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:894)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:247)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:186)
```

The gradle library entry I'm using is:

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:11.2.0'`

It seems like the `setTokenExpirationBroadcastAlarm` code isn't setting the flag. Has anyone got a workaround for this or idea of what I'm doing wrong?

My code calls this in `onActivityResult` when the user has signed in:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
    facebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

I'm testing this on a Pixel with Android 12.

Comment: If you are not in control of building the `PendingIntent`, then you can't fix it (besides just not targeting Android 12 yet). You'll want to reach out the Facebook to have them fix their library.

Comment: Looks like a fix for this is going to be released in 11.3.0.  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/997#issuecomment-914691737

Answer (score 26):

This problem was solved in the following version of the Facebook

**sdk 12.3.0**.

add/change to this line

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.3.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Facebook resolved this issue in 11.3.0 version.

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:11.3.0'

Comment: I just had 11.2.0 before the fix. Changing it to 11.3.0 helped, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to version `11.0.0` works for me. Try downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem on the Facebook SDK for Unity - be aware that at the time of this writing, the apparently fix from the Facebook SDK wasn't backported yet.

Follow the issue here
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/226